# Pydroid 3 and kivy 2.2.0+

Tags: kivy, pydroid

I can't install kivy any newer version than 2.0.0 but I need minimum 2.2.0 to work. It always stops on building wheel for kivy. It shows `ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly` It doesn't work neither for pydroid3 with python 3.09 nor python 3.11.2.

Does anyone have working wheel?